# Represent fields with value null in solr

Tags: mongodb, solr

I am fresher to solr i am trying to index a field in solr

```
 <field name="ingsQty" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

Which is a multivalued when i insert values such as

```
9,8,null,8
```

after indexing it returns the following values on query

```
9,8,8
```

how to make that null appear in the result

Comment: This is IMHO not possible. I would use a special placeholder for the `null` values.

Comment: Is this possible for non multivalued fields

Comment: With a non-multivalue field you are not indexing `null`, the field is just not present, so you can query for non-presence of a field. This is something different than adding a `null` value into a list of values of the multivalue field.